# How to merge two queries to make result like in picture?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries, how to merge the query to make result like in picture?

Query 1:

```
SELECT id_realkinbel,GROUP_CONCAT(progres) AS label FROM realkinbel
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT progres, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', BTLKeu, BTLFis, BLKeu, BLFis) separator '|') AS data FROM realkinbel;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP_CONCAT` progress as well like this:

```
SELECT id_realkinbel,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(progres AS CHAR)) AS label,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', BTLKeu, BTLFis, BLKeu, BLFis) separator '|') AS data 
FROM realkinbel;
```

But it will be better if you use some column to `GROUP BY`. Otherwise it will group all rows and return a single row.